# Get Elements using class prefix name in IE BHO using c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, internet-explorer, bho

i am working in IE Plugin using BHO.i want to get a element using class prefix(starting) name.i have already done it in javascript and jquery.

```
var myClass = $('[class^="ii gt"]');
```

and

```
var myClass = $(document).find('div[class^="ii gt"]');
```

So,the same thing i want to get in IE browser using C# BHO.How can i achieve it?

**note:** the above class name may be like `ii gt aaa` or `ii gt bbb sss`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to iterate all div elements (API IHTMLDocument3.getElementsByTagName, returned IHTMLElementCollection), then check theirs class name (IHTMLElement.className)

Comment: @ Calvin :But i dont know the exact class name.

Comment: How about IHTMLElement.className.indexOf("ii gt")==0 ?  IHTMLElement.className would return the exact class name of the element.